# Confusion with data after cross correlation

Tags: python, cross-correlation

Surely this question has been answered before in parts but I cannot find one solid answer. Ultimately I am trying to calculate the audio delay between two signals I am recording on USB microphones. With no problem I am recording the audio, reading it back into python, computing the cross correlation/convolving, and then finding the delay. When I manually create the signals (one with a delay) and feed them into my algorithm both methods find the right delay. As a test for real data I am trying to find the speed of sound between two mics (velocity = dis / time). Again, with a man-made delay of 76 frames and mic spacing of .6 meters I get a speed of sound of roughly 348.157...close enough for me.

When I try this with real recorded data no two tests have similar outputs; huge outliers, and no consistency.

- What should I try next? filtering?
- Add more mics for more accuracy?

The source signal is Guassian white noise. Any help you guys can give would be awesome.

Comment: how long is the sequence your correlating?

Comment: are you running into issues due to different signal energies? are you doing normalized cross-correlation?

Comment: Multipath can really complicate time delay measurements.  Is your data recorded indoors?

Answer (score 0):

I had done something like this and ran into similar problems a while ago, using Matlab. The audio to the microphones was speech or whistling in my case. I was estimating the delay between two mics to find the direction sound was arriving from.

The audio data from the mics probably has oscillations of some kind (like a sum of sinusoids plus some noise), at least at certain locations. The cross-correlation of one such waveform with a delayed version of it will be a signal with oscillations. This would look like [this example](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/cross-correlation-of-phase-lagged-sine-wave.html), but possibly decaying slowly. I've seen something similar in [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31477/signals-cross-correlation).

The cross-correlation peak should indicate the delay, but there are multiple peaks so you may be detecting the wrong one. Since your input signal is not a pure sine-wave, the largest peak should be the delay but it would be hard to guarantee that in a hardware system. This may be why you're getting inconsistent results.

Since you know the distance between the two microphones (and the system's sampling rate), you can estimate the maximum *expected* delay (in a number of samples), as the time it would take for sound to travel the full distance between the mics (0.6 meters). Then you should search for the cross-correlation peak only in the first such number samples, rather than in the full waveform.

Low-pass filtering may also be helpful if you're just interested in the delay. The higher frequency components can create peaks in the cross-correlation sooner (oscillations with a smaller period). In my case, I had found that a low-pass cut-off of about 1.0-1.5 kHz was adequate since my signal (speech) was wide-band and contained enough information at low frequencies for the delay estimation.